# Clang's thread sanitizer warning while using std::string in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, clang++

While working with clang's thread sanitizer we noticed data race warnings. We think it's due to std::string's copy-on-write technique not being thread safe, but we could be wrong. We reduced the warning we were seeing to this code:

```
void test3() {
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thread;

  {
    auto output = make_shared<string>();
    std::string str = "test";
    thread.reset(new std::thread([str, output]() { *output += str; }));
    // The str string now goes out of scope but due to COW
    // the captured string may not have the copy of the content yet.
  }

  thread->join();
}
```

When compiled with thread sanitizer enabled:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -O0 -g -fsanitize=thread -lpthread -o test main.cpp
```

or

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -O0 -g -fsanitize=thread -lpthread -o test main.cpp
```

And when run multiple times, it eventually produces this warning:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=30829)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7d0c0000bef8 by thread T62:
    #0 operator delete(void*) <null>:0
    ...

  Previous write of size 1 at 0x7d0c0000befd by thread T5:
    #0 std::__1::char_traits<char>::assign(char&, char const&) string:639
    ...
```

Is this a false positive from the thread sanitizer or is it a real data race? If the later,
can it be work arounded without changing the code (e.g. by passing some flags to the compiler), is this a know bug in the string implemntation (or something else)?

UPDATE: *clang --version* outputs:

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

UPDATE: [The cpp](https://gist.github.com/inetic/b73a8a0f4186c8fe034d) I use to reproduce this warning.

Comment: libc++ isn't supposed to be using COW strings, so I'd be surprised if COW strings are the cause of this.

Comment: @BartoszKP, yes, sorry, this being a COW problem was just our guess supported by the reasoning in the test case. Essentially what we need is to make the code thread safe, the problem is that sometimes we get similar warnings from inside e.g. boost::asio so we're not always in a position to change the code.

Comment: clang's thread sanitizer is a great tool, but it is very hard to interpret correctly all kinds of mutexes and other synchronization techniques. Might be the case here - I got some false alarms from it because, for example, it doesn't understand Qt's mutexes.

Answer (score 2):

[edit] Assumptions below turn out to be faulty, see link in comments. T5, not T62 is the thread spawned in the code above.

<strike>It would be useful to understand the thread ID's, but I assume that T5 is the main thread and T62 is the spawned thread. It looks like the copy is made on the main thread (before the new thread is spwaned) and destroyed on the new thread (obviously). This is safe because the new thread cannot race with the main thread before it exists.</strike>

Hence, this is a thread sanitizer bug. It failed to check whether thread T62 existed at the time of the previous write.

Comment: Yes, the thread T5 appears to be the one that started the test3 function and T62 the one that executes the lambda. [Here is the full TSan warning](https://gist.github.com/inetic/b73a8a0f4186c8fe034d#file-thread_sanitizer_warning-output). So it seems you're correct, if you don't mind I'll give this question a bit more time before I mark the answer.

Comment: That warning is rather complex. With that full context available, it's clear that neither T5 nor T62 is the main thread (!) Instead, it seems you had a `test2()` which happened to use the same memory.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/inetic/b73a8a0f4186c8fe034d#file-thread_sanitizer_warning-cpp) is the cpp code used to generate the warning (line numbers won't match, sorry). You're right that neither T5 nor T62 is the main thread, I run the test3 function many times in a separate threads to reproduce the warning more quickly. Though, there is no shared memory between each test3 invocation so I don't believe there is much difference (?).

Comment: (originally I had test1 and test2 functions in that cpp file as well, but those were testing something else and there was at no point any shared memory between any of them).

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky.  I've summarized the logic in your code below:

```
    
    In thread T62:
        Create string s (with reference count)
        Create output_1 pointing to s in the thread storage for T62 
        Create thread T5
        Create output_2 pointing to s in the thread storage for T5
    Sync point
    In thread T5:
        Append to s   ** MODIFY **
        Thread-safe decrement of reference count for s (not a sync point)
        End of output_2 lifetime
        Exit
    In thread T62:
        Thread-safe decrement of reference count for s (not a sync point)
        End of output_1 lifetime
        Deallocate s  ** MODIFY **
        Join
    Sync point
    In thread T62:
        Destroy T5
```

As far as I can tell, the standard makes no guarantees about synchronization with regard to calling the `shared_ptr` deleter:

> (20.8.2.2/4) For purposes of determining the presence of a data race, member functions shall access and modify only the shared_ptr and weak_ptr objects themselves and not objects they refer to.

I take this to mean that any modifications that do actually happen to the pointed-to object while calling a member function of the shared_ptr, such as any modifications the deleter might make, are considered to be outside the scope of the `shared_ptr`, and therefore it is not the responsibility of the `shared_ptr` to make sure they do not introduce a data race. For example, the modifications made to the string by T5 may not be visible to T62 by the time thread T62 tries to destroy it.

However, Herb Sutter, in his "Atomic<> weapons" talk, indicated he saw it as a bug to have the atomic decrement of the reference count in the `shared_ptr` destructor without both acquire and release semantics, but I'm not sure how it violates the standard.

Comment: I'm somewhat at a loss here. Doesn't that dtor run after `thread->join()`? IOW, is there still a running thread to race with?

Comment: @MSalters: Not necessarily.  The thread may have finished before the join is done. The join merely waits until the thread has exited if it hasn't exited already.

Comment: Right, now I get it. That explains your scenario. I agree, this is probably the right explanation.

Comment: @VaughnCato you are right, when I move the line *auto output = make_shared<string>();* above the opening bracket of the local scope (one line up) to postpone destruction of the output string, the warning disappears when libc++ is used. Unfortunately I still see a warning when I use libstdc++, [it looks a tiny bit different](https://gist.github.com/inetic/b73a8a0f4186c8fe034d#file-thread_sanitizer_warning-output-stdc) (did not spot it until now).

Comment: @PeterJankuliak: I'm not sure if the warning on the page you linked to is from before or after moving the line, or does it change?

Comment: Have updated the warning logs with description to avoid confusion: [this one is when the *output* string is moved out of the local scope](https://gist.github.com/inetic/b73a8a0f4186c8fe034d#file-thread_sanitizer_warning-output-stdc), and [this one is when it's left inside](https://gist.github.com/inetic/b73a8a0f4186c8fe034d#file-thread_sanitizer_warning-output3-stdc). Both use stdc++ and the warnings look consistent over multiple runs.

Comment: @PeterJankuliak: I don't see any issues with the new version of the code where the shared string is created outside the inner scope.  However, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem with clang 3.4 with either version of your code with either libc++ or libstdc++.